# A function $f$ continuous and injective is monotone.

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:**

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and injective. Show that $f$ is monotone.

Should I consider the contrapositive? Also will considering its derivative help in this example?

Comment: You do not know if $f$ is differentiable, so you cannot use the derivative.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on MathJax, you should take a look at it and use it on your following questions.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Say $f(a) < f(b)$.

Now suppose f is not stricly increasing and that there are $x < y$ such that $f(x) > f(y)$. Then we would have two possibilities, $f(a) < f(y)$ or $f(a) > f(y)$. For the first case we have $$f(a) < f(y) < f(x)$$

Use the Intermediate Value Theorem and find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, you cannot talk about derivatives since we do not know if $f$ is differentiable.

Contrapositive might work, but also a proof by contradiction works:

Suppose $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and injective.

Suppose for a contradiction that $f$ is not monotone. Then there exists some $x_0\in [a,b)$ such that there are $x_i>x_0 : i=1,2$ in $(x_0,b]$ with $f(x_0)<f(x_1)$ and $f(x_0)>f(x_2)$. Then as $f$ is continuous on $[x_1,x_2]$ (say $x_1<x_2$ without loss of generality, otherwise we can just swap indices), and as $f(x_0)\in (f(x_2),f(x_1))$, by intermediate value theorem there exists some $\xi\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(\xi)=f(x_0)$, and as $x_0\neq \xi$ this is a contradiction to injectivity.

Answer (score 1):

For kicks and giggles let's see if we can prove this directly.

Let's say we have $x \ne y$.  As $f$ is injective $f(x) \ne f(y)$. By intermediate value theorem, for all values, $d$, between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ there are values $e_d$ between $x$ and $y$ so that $f(e_d) = d$--- for *all* values between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.   Because $f$ is injective no *other* values will map into a value between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.  Thus any $c$ between $x$ and $y$ can not be mapped to an value outside of the interval $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ so $f(c)$ must be between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.  As $x, y,$ and $c$ are arbitrary.  $f$ is monotonic.

Okay... Aaron Maroja's  contrapositive proof was easier and more convincing...